# How to software interrupt a running function in C?

Tags: c, windows-xp, x86, mingw, interrupt

I want to generate an interrupt while a function is running and then I want the CPU to execute some specific ISR, and after finishing the ISR, the function will resume executing. I am using Windows XP and the MinGW compiler.

Comment: Are you talking about a hardware interrupt and hardware ISR?

Comment: Please be more specific. What do you try to accomplish?

Comment: @ChrisW no hardware is there actually I want first to generate interrupt somehow and handle it later on I will do it on actual hardware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> no hardware is there actually I want first to generate interrupt somehow and handle it later on I will do it on actual hardware

A real hardware interrupt will toggle one of the CPU pins and cause it to dispatch to the ISR. I can't think of any really transparent way to emulate that.

One way to pause the currently-running function might be to use the [SuspendThread function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686345(v=vs.85).aspx), and then use a different thread to run the ISR.

A different possibility to investigate might be to use [Fibers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682661(v=vs.85).aspx).

---

**Edit**

As [cxxl's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13819216/49942) suggested, another possibility is to use a real-time priority thread:

- Have two threads, one to run your function and another thread to run the emulated ISR
- Use the "CPU affinity" function on both threads, to ensure they both run on the same CPU
- Set the priority of the ISR thread to "realtime"

Then, whenever you allow the ISR-emulating thread run, it will pre-empt the other thread.

Comment: could you please elaborate more your answer .I want to do like this but how to  proceed?

Comment: @user1871762 "How to proceed" would be to read the documentation for the API functions that I mentioned (see [Thread functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684847(v=vs.85).aspx#thread_functions)), and decide whether they can meet your requirements. I can't elaborate more unless you are more clear about what solution you are trying to implement, and/or be more specific about what your difficulty is. See also the comments/questions below cxxl's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Get the Windows Driver Kit from here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/gg487428.aspx . It contains headers and libraries to write a device driver. And a device driver is what you need to write, if you are to handle interrupts.

You can write a device driver and use DPCs, that is sort of the worker function of the ISR. These DPCs can be called in software and are still executed at a higher priority than any user mode code. The ISR itself is usually very short, just handles the interrupt, saves its data and hands control over to the DPC.

I doubt you can do that in MinGW, but I guess you need MS Visual C, but there is an Express Edition which is free of charge. See here: http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/visual-studio-express-products

You **are** sure you need a interrupt? You can do a lot in user mode with admin rights and realtime priority...

Comment: @user1871762 cxxl's answer is to write a device driver: which you need, if and only if you want to handle a hardware interrupt on Windows. If instead you want to write simulation code which runs on windows, but which you will later port to an embedded non-Windows system, then instead of writing a device driver you should consider the answers which suggest using a multi-threaded user-mode application for your simulation.

Comment: @ChrisW I don't think it makes much sense to simulate hardware interrupts for another platform using threads in Windows. The hardware, OS and timing will be completely different, there will be almost no similarities between Windows and the embedded system, so I don't think there will be any gain from it.

Comment: @Lundin It's unclear what the OP means when he says "later on I will do it on actual hardware" ... I took it literally, as meaning "run the code *on* (embedded) hardware"; but perhaps you're right, and he meant "generate the interrupt *using* an (external) hardware device".

Comment: @ChrisW you took it rightly. later on I have to do this thing on (embedded)hardware.

Answer (score 0):

As others said, quite a vague question.

Some CPU's have ways to force/fake an interrupt via software, you could investigate that.
(I don't know about x86, I'm embedded dev)

Within an OS you may/should be able to interrupt one process/thread with another. Again, I'm not a Win programmer so can't really say.

Otherwise, depending on specifics, you can have some main loop running which your subroutine is called from, and every time round it checks for the "interrupting condition" (whatever that may be) and either branches or sets a flag to indicate something has happened / needs to happen.

Comment: x86 has an `int` opcode called a "software interrupt", but it dispatches the thread which invokes that opcode.